# Storing images in MySQL for back-up purposes - not serving them - is that also really bad?

Tags: mysql, image, text, blob

I have read plenty of comments articles concerning you should not store images or use a MySQL database as a substitution for the file disk system. With other files; Store your files on disk, not in MySQL.

But in all articles I have read so far, they use the same example demonstrating why it is bad. They are serving images directly from the database, with other words, for each request it somehow includes a database transaction. I totally understand why that is not a good idea.

However, I am in a situation where I want to store, as an example, a User's profile image as a backup in the MySQL database together with their regular data (such as username, password, etc). Serving the images is handled by another system.

So I am thinking of a tables that looks like:

```
+--------------------+
| User               |
+--------------------+
| id (int)           |
| username (varchar) |
| password (varchar) |
| image (mediumtext) |
+--------------------+
```

So I have some questions so I understand more of the drawbacks, and if they are severe enough.

q1) Does having a blob/text data-types mixed with other non-blob/text data-types (int, varchars, etc) have a severe impact when doing queries?

q2) Even if the queries does not mention the blob/text field? In my case, the "image" column? (meaning not `SELECT * FROM`, but instead maybe `SELECT id, username, password FROM`)

q3) Is the negative performance linear the more users I might have? Meaning if I have 10 or 100,000 users, will the performance still be the same for each read look up?

q4) Is there any difference, performance wise, if data is stored in a blob vs text?

I know everything and anything will impact performance in a negative way. That's life. But I want to try and understand in what way, and how much of an impact does it have, so I can make my own call if it is a good or bad idea for my own project.

Any feedback is appreciated!

Comment: keep the image path in your database and store images into a directory.

Comment: That doesn't answer my questions though. I want to understand the implications and how server they are, so I can make own call for the current project and future projects.

Comment: Write a script to populate test table with/without blob with some random generated data, then make some benchmarks and publish answer here. I am interrested, too.

Comment: well in simple terms, you put the work of serving that image data on the database. In general, the less [optional] strain on a db the better, using the "recommended" method is akin to using pointers instead of copying values for functional arguments in a language